# URL Encoding in AlamoFire 4.X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm trying to get a JPG file from a public webserver without any kind of authentication. Coding is done in Swift 3 with AlamoFire 4.4

urlString has following value:
https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/36406120/m%3D900_k%3D1_a%3D1/v2?client_application_id=29771&webp=true&sig=97ac488f1336f41d9f3e4a67e6bf99b3bd1aadfb6c9631a6097ff5b4a729a94e

```
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let myParameters: [String : AnyObject]  = ["myImage": image, "myBlurredImage": blurredImage, "index": index as AnyObject]
        let croppedSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollViewWidth!, height: self.scrollViewHeight!)
        self.apicounterPerRequest += 1


        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: myParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .validate()
            .response { response in
                let myImage = myParameters["myImage"] as! UIImageView
                let myBlurredImage = myParameters["myBlurredImage"] as! UIImageView
                let index = myParameters["index"] as! Int
                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: response.data!) {
                    myImage.image = downloadedImage
                    self.displayed500PxPhoto[index].uiimage = downloadedImage
                    myBlurredImage.image = PhotoManager.imageWithSize(downloadedImage, size: croppedSize)
                    completion({
                        print("Done Downloading")
                    })

                } else {
                    print("Error : \(response.data)")
                }

                if response.error != nil {
                    print(response.error!)
                    self.showAlert("One or more photos could not be downloaded. Please try again.")
                    completion({
                        throw response.error!
                    })
                }
        }
```

I'm getting a 403 Error:

```
Error : Optional(409 bytes)
responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(403))
```

I'm pretty sure there is an encoding problem with reserved characters in the URL posted above but couldn't yet figure out how to properly tell AlamoFire on how to encode it. Any clues are highly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I notice you are using -  encoding: URLEncoding.default which means you are passing parameters in the query string.  Can you manually add the parameters to the query string you provided and see what the result is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make it simple

These are some tips to help you:

- The default method is `get` so you don't need to pass it.
- The parameters might need to be empty (because I don't think that you want to pass the a UIImageView)
- Do not add extra unneeded work by storing the `["myImage": image]` and then getting it back again.
- Do not make unnecessary casting to `AnyObject` for the index because `Alamofire` accept `Parameters = [String: Any]`
- The response is data so use the `responseData` function

Here is my working sample:

```
func testingImage(_ completion: @escaping ((UIImage?) -> Swift.Void)) {
    let urlString = "https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/36406120/m%3D900_k%3D1_a%3D1/v2?client_application_id=29771&webp=true&sig=97ac488f1336f41d9f3e4a67e6bf99b3bd1aadfb6c9631a6097ff5b4a729a94e"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return completion(nil) }

    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseData {
        guard let data = $0.data else { return completion(nil) }
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return completion(nil) }

        completion(image)
    }
}
```

and you can call it like this

```
testingImage() { self.imageView.image = $0 }
```

`$0` means the returned parameter (used if you don't want to specify a name) instead if `response in`

Comment: Because I didn't realize I can do that.... I'm sorry. I just did. Thanks again for your help and have a great weekend.